# Identifying VBA routine

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi to give some context the code below is from an Access database that was left to me from the previous employee, Unfortunately I am not very good at VBA.

I would appreciate any help in identifying its purpose.

```
Private Sub Command83_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command83_Click

Dim stDialStr As String
Dim PrevCtl As Control
Const ERR_OBJNOTEXIST = 2467
Const ERR_OBJNOTSET = 91
Const ERR_CANTMOVE = 2483

Set PrevCtl = Screen.PreviousControl

If TypeOf PrevCtl Is TextBox Then
  stDialStr = IIf(VarType(PrevCtl) > V_NULL, PrevCtl, "")
ElseIf TypeOf PrevCtl Is ListBox Then
  stDialStr = IIf(VarType(PrevCtl) > V_NULL, PrevCtl, "")
ElseIf TypeOf PrevCtl Is ComboBox Then
  stDialStr = IIf(VarType(PrevCtl) > V_NULL, PrevCtl, "")
Else
  stDialStr = ""
End If

Application.Run "utility.wlib_AutoDial", stDialStr

Exit_Command83_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command83_Click:
If (Err = ERR_OBJNOTEXIST) Or (Err = ERR_OBJNOTSET) Or (Err = ERR_CANTMOVE) Then
  Resume Next
End If
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command83_Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Const **ERR_...** are [Error Codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864/en)

The script checks whether ***PrevCtl*** is a Text-, List or ComboBox and sets the string of ***stDialStr*** depending on the Box. In the end it starts an external AutoDial program with the given parameter.

```
Application.Run "utility.wlib_AutoDial", stDialStr
```

Comment: And it's intended to run when you click a button on a form.